# Mac and windows 7 file sharing specific user

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, file-sharing, samba

I try to share a specific directory to my windows 7 computer, but I want it to use a specific user that I created on my mac to connect to it.

I saw this tutorial: http://www.trickyways.com/2010/06/how-to-access-mac-files-from-windows-7/ wich is exactly what I want to do, but it ain't working.

For some reason, it never prompts me for username/password when I try to connect on my mac when I'm on Windows 7. On top of that, when I set the permission "No Access" to the "Everyone" user on my mac, my windows computer simply don't see the directory. If I set the permission to "Read/Write" or "Read only" it works.

I simply don't want that everyone in my workgroup to be able to read my files. I want to create specific users on my mac and share them to the persons I want...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you enable SMB sharing? This should work as described in the article.

Comment: Yes I did enable SMB sharing :/